# Ruby: how to check if variable exists within a hash definition

Tags: ruby, hash, if-statement

I'm new to Ruby. Is there a way to do the following?

```
hash = {
  :key1  => defined? value1 ? value1 : nil, 
  :key2  => defined? value2 ? value2 : nil
}

puts hash[:key1] # outputs: ["expression"]
```

The above code stores the expression, instead of the **value** (if it is defined) or **nil** (if it is not defined).

Comment: Could you try to explain a little bit more? I've read your question three times and still don't understand what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `lambda`, or `Proc`.

```
hash = {
  :key1 => lambda { defined?(value1) ? value1 : nil },
  :key2 => lambda { defined?(value2) ? value1 : nil }
}

hash[:key1].call
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Kernel.html#method-i-lambda

Comment: Thanks for this. Just found that by adding parenthesis does what I was looking for ....   `hash = {:key1  => (defined? value1) ? value1 : nil}`

Answer (score 2):

d11wtg answer will do. Also, by adding parentheses, the values are stored as expected:

```
hash = {
  :key1  => (defined? value1) ? value1 : nil, 
  :key2  => (defined? value2) ? value2 : nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to do?

> hash[:key].nil?

will return true or false, depending if the key exists. Not sure if that's what you are looking for.