# Ruby testing for definition of a variable

Tags: ruby

I know there are other questions similar such as:

1. [Ruby: how to check if variable exists within a hash definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903656/ruby-how-to-check-if-variable-exists-within-a-hash-definition)
2. [Checking if a variable is defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288715/checking-if-a-variable-is-defined-in-ruby)

But the answers aren't fully satisfactory.

I have:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > a=Hash.new
 => {} 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > a['one']="hello"
 => "hello"
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :006 > defined?(a['one']['some']).nil?
 => false 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :007 > a['one']['some'].nil?
 => true
```

It seems like:

```
if a['one']['some'].nil?
  a['one']['some']=Array.new
end
```

would be sufficient. Is this correct? Would this be correct for any data type? Is defined? needed in this case?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confusing two concepts. One is if a variable is defined, and another is if a Hash key is defined. Since a hash is, at some point, a variable, then it must be defined.

```
defined?(a)
# => nil

a = { }
# => {}

defined?(a)
# => "local-variable"

a.key?('one')
# => false

a['one'] = 'hello'
# => 'hello'

a.key?('one')
# => true
```

Something can be a key and `nil` at the same time, this is valid. There is no concept of defined or undefined for a Hash. It is all about if the key exists or not.

The only reason to test with `.nil?` is to distinguish between the two possible non-true values: `nil` and `false`. If you will never be using `false` in that context, then calling `.nil?` is unnecessarily verbose. In other words, `if (x.nil?)` is equivalent to `if (x)` provided `x` will never be literally `false`.

What you probably want to employ is the `||=` pattern that will assign something if the existing value is `nil` or `false`:

```
# Assign an array to this Hash key if nothing is stored there
a['one']['hello'] ||= [ ]
```

**Update:** Edited according to remarks by [Bruce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6310/bruce).

Comment: Technically 'defined?' returns a string or nil, not true/false.

Comment: thx for detailed answer - makes more sense; will need to work with different ways of handling

Comment: @Bruce You're correct, I hadn't realized. Answer updated accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I had to dig a number of pages deep into Google, but I eventually found [this useful bit](http://ruby.runpaint.org/variables) from the Ruby 1.9 spec:

"In all cases the test [defined?] is conducted without evaluating the operand."

So what's happening is that it looks at:

```
a['one']['some']
```

and says "that is sending the "operator []" message to the 'a' object - that is a method call!" and the result of defined? on that is "method".

Then when you check against nil?, the string "method" clearly isn't nil.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @tadmans answer, what you actually did in your example was to check, if the string `"some"` is included in the string `"hello"` which is stored in your hash at the position `"one"`.

```
a = {}
a['one'] = 'hello'
a['one']['some'] # searches the string "some" in the hash at key "one"
```

A more simple example:

```
b = 'hello'
b['he'] # => 'he'
b['ha'] # => nil
```

That's why the `defined?` method did not return `nil`, as you expected, but `"method"`.

Comment: A reasonable thought, but it turns out that defined? doesn't evaluate its parameter, so it never bothers to figure out that a['one'] evaluates to "hello".